# How to allow user to view HTML page if is logged in using PHP

Tags: php, html

Quick question here. How can I make sure that a user can view a HTML page only if they are logged in (using PHP). I understand that I must use $_SESSION to state whether the user is logged in, but how should I check on an HTML page if the user is logged in if all I am using is HTML code?

I read up that an option is to change the .htacess file to allow PHP in an HTML file? If so, where can I find the .htaccess file on the WWW stream? (I am using FileZilla and cannot seem to find it).

Basically, I do not want a user to access a URL page (even if they have the URL link) without being logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: Make your html file a php file, then just put a small php snippet at the top to check authorization. If authorized just fall through and render the rest of the html, if not, return an error and stop execution.

Comment: @Kallmanation - thanks! so I would just change my .html to .php? Am I required to add specific tags to declare that I am using HTML in a php file?

Comment: No, php actually operates in the opposite way, _everything_ is considered html unless you specifically mark it as php by placing the `<?php .. ?>` tags around the code.

Comment: @Kallmanation - Oh, got it! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Kallmanation - Sorry to bother you again. But do you by any chance know if I will need to change my .htacess file to allow HTML in a PHP file?

Comment: The standard is to allow html inside php files, I honestly don't know of a way to disallow html inside of php...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kalmanation's comment.

I prefer to make a separate page (API) that contains code LIKE below at bottom which checks the $_SESSION variable. Then, as already stated, change your html pages to php and at the top of each page use an 'include' or 'require' statement. If the file containing the code below was named logincheck.php, all other pages (now php instead of html) might use:

```
<?php
    include 'logincheck.php'
?>
```

---

```
<?php 
    if(!$_SESSION['logged_in'] || isset($_POST['LogOut'])) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=FALSE;
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-360000, '/');
        }
        session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Also check out which is best for your application: require, require_once, include, include_once.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Thank you for that! That is really helpful! :)